# For Loops With User Inputs

Tags: c#, .net, string, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to code this in C#.

Write a c# program with for loop that will perform the following output:

```
What would  you like to say?
 HELLO
How many times  would you like this phrase to be repeated?
4
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
```

I'm kind of confused on what to do and this is what I have so far;

```
string word;
int number;
string total;

Console.WriteLine("What would you like to say?");
word = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like it repeated?");
number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

total = word + number;

for (string word = total; );
```

Comment: try `for(int i = 0 ; i < number; i++) Console.WriteLine(word);`

Comment: The solution is easy as you can see, but it is better for you to read something about FOR..LOOP http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/for-loop.php

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will read about the loops as well, thanks for the link.